# How to vertically center a font glyph?

Tags: ios

I have a `UIButton` with title "⟳". The title does not appear to be vertically centered due to the position of "⟳".

[image]

I understand that offsets of the `UIButton` can be changed to solve the problem in this instance.

Can anyone point out if there is any other way to vertically center the "⟳" glyph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this image, all 4 green buttons are using 64-pt System font, with the `.titleLabel` background set to yellow:

[image]

As you can see with the top button, an upper-case "O" is centered vertically and horizontally.

The "⟳" unicode symbol you are using is more like a lower-case character - as seen in the 2nd button.

By itself, in the 3rd button, we see it appears "shifted" down and to the left.

The symbol in the bottom button is center-aligned by adjusting the Title Edge Insets:

```
.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 14, right: 0)
```